# Hangout on Air App

Tags: google-plus, google-hangouts

I was trying to create a hangout app, and connect it to my youtube channel.I have created the app but unable to connect it to youtube channel. How can i do so. Is there any way to create a "Hangout On Air" app.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "connect it to youtube channel" in this case? What, exactly, are you trying to do? The hangout API has some method that let you determine when you are on air, but it isn't clear if they do what you want.

Comment: Hangout on air, allows you to broadcast your video to youtube channel. I want this functionality. my current hangout app does not allow me to do so. If i can create a hangout on air app and give a link on my website to this app, my purpose is served. So is there any way to create a "hangout on air" app.

Comment: So you're saying you want to write an app that streams something (what?) to a YouTube channel? Will this be streaming it on top of a video feed for someone else who is in the HoA?

Comment: Did you solution your problem? I have the same

Answer (score 0):

Hangouts apps work for both standard hangouts and on-air hangouts. If you have an app for Hangouts, then you just need to start an On-Air Hangout instead and start your app. Then, the Youtube broadcast and post-event archiving is built in.

Examples here (https://developers.google.com/+/hangouts/button) show how to make a button on your website to start either a standard hangout or on-air hangout, and automatically start your app.  Although, at the moment, the automatic app starting for on-air seems to be broken ([Were Hangouts On Air example buttons recently broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26836455/were-hangouts-on-air-example-buttons-recently-broken)).

Answer (score 0):

You dont need to write a hangout app to connect to your youtube channel. By default if you start a Hangout on Air, the video will stream live through your youtube account. Use the below code to start a HoA.

```
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js" async defer></script>
<div id="placeholder-div4"></div>
<script>
  gapi.hangout.render('placeholder-div4', {
    'topic': 'hats',
    'render': 'createhangout',
    'hangout_type': 'onair',
    'initial_apps': [{'app_id' : '184219133185', 'start_data' : 'dQw4w9WgXcQ', 'app_type' : 'ROOM_APP' }],
  });
```

more details : https://developers.google.com/+/hangouts/button

If you want to get the youtube url and stream the same in your website, watch the tutorial below.

```
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Al4SbeVyLm4
```